# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException was thrown (Xamarin Android)

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a left drawer menu for android app by using Xamarin Android. I followed the tutorial from here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-left-drawer-layout/

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin 4.8.0.756. My Xamarin.Android and SDK is 8.1. When installing the Android Support Library v7, I use the AppCompat Version 25.4.0.2 which is targeting MonoAndroid Version 7.0

Refer to the tutorial, I stuck at the step 9. Having an error displayed on layout

[image]

I have another error at the `menu.xml` as well.

[image]

I've been advised that, it might be cause of the android SDK compatibility. But it looked just fine when I'm doing the library installation.

**EDIT**

I found out that when I added the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` will appear

Comment: Did you add Support libraries (nugets), if so, try to clean and then build the solution, specially if you add some C# code, it happens a lot?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I've added the support libraries. I dragged the toolbar support libraries from my toolbox.

Comment: Please paste your XML and C# codes here

Comment: I haven't done anything in C# yet. I am following exactly in this tutorial https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-left-drawer-layout/ . My code all same as the tutorial. But I only do until step 9 as I'm having the error on the layout in the step 9

Comment: You mentioned in your first comment here: "I dragged the toolbar support libraries from my toolbox.", that's way I asked about your code.

Comment: Try delete bin and obj, and then restart VS.